# Preventing Javascript XSS by replacing all the bracket characters

Tags: javascript, jsp, xss

I'm using MongoDB for backend, which makes me believe I shouldn't be worried about XSS in my DB.

For the "frontend" I'm generating pages via JSP. Now, I'm religiously escaping user-generated content (which should be plain text - no Javascript or HTML tags), but I don't trust myself 100%.

After reading some pointers about XSS, I'm wondering whether the following hack would fail-proof my website.

When consuming user-generated input on the server side, I want to replace all the brackets in user-generated content , e.g. `()` by `[]`. And I want to replace all the `<>` symbols by:
single left-pointing angle quotation mark:   ‹
single right-pointing angle quotation mark:  ›

Now, I'm assuming that without `()` and `<>` it's pretty much impossible to write a piece of JavaScript XSS.

Will this hack work or am I missing something?

Comment: There's [**modules**](https://github.com/yahoo/xss-filters) for that, maybe you should trust Yahoo instead ?

Comment: Either deeply study the underlying rules of HTML and Javascript or do not experiment and use existing tools. Many times I thought I am safe if I replace this or that and many times I was wrong. And if you insist on regex replacement, use character **whitelist** not blacklist.

Comment: Also replacing rounded brackets from user input is pretty stupid - they are valid form of punctuation.

Comment: i don't think that's enough, depending on context. there's a lot of ways to escape things, see the https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet for a somewhat historical but still enlightening reinforcement.

Comment: Thanks! Adeneo - I didn't know about XSS filters/modules, and I'll look into using them; 

Thomas, I don't think my users will care for [] instead of (), and I've heard about whitelist over blacklist, but for my application I have to allow unrestricted alphanumeric + punctuation, so I have to allow enough for XSS attacks;

@dandavis, thanks, I've read some OWASP resources, but didn't see that one, which is very useful.

Comment: What content type are you using? If your content type is truly `text/plain` and you specify a character encoding, you are safe. Otherwise, your comment about "plain text" doesn't make sense to me.

When interpolating user-controlled data into your JSP, do you know what 
[context](http://security.coverity.com/document/2013/Mar/fixing-xss-a-practical-guide-for-developers.html)
it's in?

Comment: Thanks @coastalhacking . Pls excuse my poor terminology. My users fill out forms which are displayed for my company's agents inside <div>'s or pre-populated into other forms using [jquery-populate](http://davestewart.io/resources/javascript/jQuery/demos/populate-demo.html), so I guess after reading your response, my contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" , but really, the users are not supposed to enter HTML-formatted text or javascript. After reading your comment, I suspect that the set of contexts is very limited. Data shouldn't go to href/URL attributes, CSS. But of cz I can have a glitch.

Comment: @LevRatinov How do you populate the JSON going into your jquery `.populate` calls? Is it all 100% fetched via XHR? Or do you sometimes interpolate data like so in a JSP: `<script ...>$('#someid').populate(${some.foo})</script>` where `some.foo` is dynamic?

Comment: @coastalhacking :   <script>$('#someid').populate($.parseJSON('<%=StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript(jsonString)%> ')); </script>, where jsonString is read from MongoDb. (Scriplets are bad, I know). In addition to XSS hole in populate, I'm worried about forgetting to escape something somewhere. My website is dynamic - the "user" signs in and depending on their role (customer/sales/root) the same URL will have different content; I'm not using any framework (I hacked my own MVC). Are there any best practices or testing tool to protect me against XSS vulnerabilities as I'm changing the code?

Comment: @LevRatinov Do you consistently use the Apache Commons `StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript‌​` library when injecting data into a JavaScript single-quoted string context (nested in a script data context), like shown above? Also, what escaper are you using for the `<div>` contexts, `escapeHtml4`?

Comment: @coastalhacking, yes, exactly as you said: StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript‌​ for javascript (but I'm using both single and double quotes, depending on where I'm copy pasting my code from) and escapeHtml4 for <div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've stated or alluded to the following in the comments or question above, paraphrased:

- Tainted data is interpolated in a div data state context, e.g.: `<div> tainted data here </div>`
- Tainted data is interpolated in a nested context: JavaScript single/double-quoted → script data state: `<script>$('#someid').populate($.parseJSON('<%=StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript‌​(jsonString)%>'));</script>`
- You use Apache Commons JavaScript string escaper [`StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript‌​`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeEcmaScript(java.lang.String)) for the aforementioned JavaScript contexts
- You will filter out `<` and `>` characters

I don't see any way for XSS to occur given the above. If you *do not* escape the `<` and `>` then your code [might be susceptible to some weirdness](https://communities.coverity.com/blogs/security/2012/11/16/did-i-do-that-html-5-js-escapers-3) regarding script data escape states. That weirdness could possibly lead to an XSS.

Instead of filtering, I recommend escaping the data using the Coverity Security Library [Escape.jsString](http://coverity.github.io/coverity-security-library/com/coverity/security/Escape.html#jsString%28java.lang.String%29) method, which escapes `<` and `>`. (Full disclosure: I worked at Coverity and committed to that library.)

Comment: Thanks, CSL looks like exactly what I need and I had trouble finding a good escaping library for Java.